# Why kubernetes doesn't allow RoleRef of RoleBinding to be updated?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Kubernetes doesn't allow RoleRef of RoleBinding to be updated.
When I command like below, kubernetes shows error:"cannot change roleRef"

```
$ kubectl apply -f - << EOF
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-crb
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: user@acme.com
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF
clusterrolebinding "test-crb" created

$ kubectl apply -f - << EOF
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-crb
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: user@acme.com
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF
The ClusterRoleBinding "test-crb" is invalid: roleRef: Invalid value: rbac.RoleRef{APIGroup:"rbac.authorization.k8s.io", Kind:"ClusterRole", Name:"view"}: cannot change roleRef
```

What I want to know is the reason.
Why kubernetes doesn't allow users to update RoleRef?
Is there some special reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

roleRef is immutable,You need to delete and recreate the referenced role/clusterorle.  Here is the related [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrolebinding-example).

> After you create a binding, you cannot change the Role or ClusterRole
> that it refers to. If you try to change a binding's roleRef, you get a
> validation error. If you do want to change the roleRef for a binding,
> you need to remove the binding object and create a replacement.

**> There are two reasons for this restriction:**

> 1. Making roleRef immutable allows granting someone update permission on
>    an existing binding object, so that they can manage the list of
>    subjects, without being able to change the role that is granted to
>    those subjects.

> 2. A binding to a different role is a fundamentally
>    different binding. Requiring a binding to be deleted/recreated in
>    order to change the roleRef ensures the full list of subjects in the
>    binding is intended to be granted the new role (as opposed to enabling
>    or accidentally modifying only the roleRef without verifying all of
>    the existing subjects should be given the new role's permissions).